# Replacing ascii codes in php

Tags: php

I've created a pdf generator from Wordpress content, which works great. But one of the problems I have is replacing characters with php... I'm really hoping there's just a big list that I can copy and paste, does one exist, hopefully in the format below?

Here's an example of my list (that I've just started):

```
    $str=array(
    '&#8220;' => '"',
    '&#8221;' => '"',
    '&#8222;' => '"',
    '&#8230;' => '...',
    '&#8217;' => '\'',
    '&#8211;' => '-',
    '&nbsp;' => ' '
    );
```

Or is there a function or easier way to do this? I don't want to manually enter a billion codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`html_entity_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) will *convert all HTML entities to their applicable characters*.